# Sort file list by date

Tags: php, wordpress

With the code below I am generating a list of pdfs located in a directory on my server.  I'd like to have the results sort by date, most recent first oldest last.

Here it is in action : http://mt-spacehosting.com/fisheries/plans/northeast-multispecies/

```
<?php 
$sub = ($_GET['dir']); 
$path = 'groundfish-meetings/';
$path = $path . "$sub"; 
$dh = opendir($path); 
$i=1; 

while (($file = readdir($dh)) !==   false) { 
    if($file != "." && $file != "..") { 
        if (substr($file, -4, -3) =="."){
         echo "$i. <option value='" . home_url('/groundfish-meetings/' . $file) .         "'>$file</option>";
         } $i++; 
        } 
     } closedir($dh); 
?>
</select>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use PHP's [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function and a custom sorting function like this:

```
<?php
$sub = ($_GET['dir']); 
$path = 'groundfish-meetings/';
$path = $path . "$sub";
$file_list = glob($path."*.pdf");

function sort_by_mtime($file1,$file2) {
$time1 = filemtime($file1);
$time2 = filemtime($file2);
if ($time1 == $time2) {
    return 0;
}
return ($time1 < $time2) ? 1 : -1;
}
usort($file_list ,"sort_by_mtime");
$i = 1;
foreach($file_list as $file)
{
  echo "$i. <option value='" . home_url('/groundfish-meetings/' . $file) .            
"'>$file</option>";
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I got that one working, but the directory is being listed in the option text.  Any way to remove that?

Comment: Yeah. Use:
    echo "$i. <option value='" . home_url('/groundfish-meetings/' . $file)."'>".str_replace(dirname($file).'/', '', $file)."</option>";

Comment: I ended up having to edit the echo line to generate the correct link url, but you got me there!    echo "$i. <option value='" . home_url($file) ."'>".str_replace(dirname($file).'/', '', $file)."</option>";

Comment: One more thought, how would I remove the .pdf from the display title.

Comment: Replace `$file` with `str_replace('.pdf', '', $file)` in the above said line

Answer (score 0):

This would get all files in path/to/files as an array and then sort that array by the file's mtime

```
$files = glob('path/to/files/*.*');
usort($files, function($a, $b) {
    return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);
});
```